# Apache config problems for Roots.io/Bedrock + Capistrano

Tags: apache, wordpress, capistrano3

I'm new with Roots.io/Bedrock, so please forgive me if im asking something stupid.
So currently I'm using Bedrock + Capistrano to deploy my wordpress site. The Capistrano part is working fine. My only problem is the Apache config.

How should I define the DocumentRoot to make Bedrock working?

Directory structure:

```
/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/current -> /var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/releases/20141028115909
/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/releases
/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/repo
/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/revisions.log
/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/shared
```

My current Vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    suPHP_Engine        On
    suPHP_ConfigPath    /etc/php5/vhosts/mydomain.com/
    suPHP_UserGroup     devsunnywebhu vhostusers
    AddHandler          x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .html
    suPHP_AddHandler    x-httpd-php

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin support@mydomain.com

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/current/web

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/current/web>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            AllowOverride ALL
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "localhost" loopback

    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" loopback
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "ip6-localhost" loopback

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-access.log combined env=!loopback
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And im getting the following error from Apache:

```
File "/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/releases/20141028115909/web/index.php" is not in document root of Vhost "/var/www/mydomain.com/teszt/current"
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody faces the same problem, its a suPHP caused error.
To solve it you need to disable `check_vhost_docroot` in the `/etc/suphp.conf` file.

```
check_vhost_docroot=false
```